# Laravel eloquent multiple WHERE with OR AND OR and LIKE?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have ( or am trying to make ) this query in Laravel

The problem I have is with the `$orThose`
I want to query `LIKE`.

The data in that field can be many things, but there will always be a key work like "L3" or "ICU" in the field.

Can you do a `LIKE` query in this case

```
$matchThese = ['link.hos_id' => $hos_id, 'outcome.otc_otrdischargedate' => $td];
$orThose = ['outcome.otc_outcome' => '@ICU@', 'outcome.otc_outcome' => '@I.C.U@'];

$todaysReferrals = DB::table('link')
->join('daily_link', 'link.lnk_id', '=', 'daily_link.dlk_lnkid')
->join('demographic', 'link.lnk_dmgid', '=', 'demographic.dmg_id')
->join('admission', 'link.lnk_admid', '=', 'admission.adm_id')
->join('or_call', 'admission.adm_calid', '=', 'or_call.cal_id')
->join('admission_score', 'admission.adm_scoreid', '=', 'admission_score.ascore_id')
->join('diagnosis', 'link.lnk_dgnid', '=', 'diagnosis.dgn_id')
->join('outcome', 'link.lnk_otcid', '=', 'outcome.otc_id')
->where($matchThese)
->orWhere($orThose)
->get();
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use `like` and `not like` with `%` in `where()` and `orWhere()` methods:

```
->where('column', 'like', '%pattern%')
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses

If you need to use multiple `AND` do like this:

```
->where($condition)
->where($anotherCondition)
```

If you want to use `OR` do this:

```
->where($condition)
->orWhere($anotherCondition)
```

To combine multiple `AND` and `OR` do [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses):

```
->where('name', '=', 'John')
->orWhere(function ($query) {
    $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
          ->where('title', '<>', 'Admin');
})
```

Comment: Can you do a `not like` as-well? In other words. `not containing this phrase`. I suppose something like  `->where('title', '<>', '%Admin%')` might work

Comment: Sure, I've added it to the answer. You should use `not like` operator for this. For example, `->where('title', 'not like', '%Admin%')`

Answer (score 17):

In this scenario **Parameter Grouping** Should be pretty much useful to use combination of multiple **AND** & **OR**. Here are some demo examples of how it can be implemented.

```
if ($request->search) {
             
     $users = User::where('type', '=',  'Customer')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('name', "like", "%" . $request->search . "%");
            $query->orWhere('mobile', "like", "%" . $request->search . "%");
        })->get();   
  }
```

It depicts:

```
select * from users where type = 'Customer' and ([name as searched] or [mobile as searched])
```

Now there is another example which is:

```
DB::table('users')
            ->where('name', '=', 'Rohan')
            ->orWhere(function ($query) {
                $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
                      ->where('title', '<>', 'Admin');
            })->get();
```

It depicts:

```
select * from users where name = 'Rohan' or (votes > 100 and title <> 'Admin')
```

I hope with the help of these you can solve the issue.

Answer (score 10):

Hi Please find the reference for where condition both with 'or' and 'and'

Table stocks

[image]

```
$name='appl';
$type=1;
$stocks = DB::table('stocks')
            ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%')
            ->orWhere('company_name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%')
            ->where('exchange_id', '=', $type)
            ->get();
$results = json_decode($stocks, true);
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$matchThese = ['title' => post('title'), 'slug' => post('slug')];
return Blog::where($matchThese)->get();
```

Comment: Hi Andre, and welcome to SO!  This could be a pretty great answer.  Can you elaborate on some of the syntax so if the OP does return to review your suggestion the answer is clear to them from the start?

Comment: The eloquent get() would return a JSON compatable array. **Blog** is the Model class, the where() search through an associative array that contains the search query for the WHERE clause

Answer (score 3):

```
public function searchData(Request $request)
{
  return Phonebook::where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->SearchQuery.'%')->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'.$request->SearchQuery.'%')->orWhere('phone', 'like', '%'.$request->SearchQuery.'%')->get();
}
```

Here I have Searched the name, email and phone number from Phonebook Model using **where**, **orwhere** and **like**